# How can I group 'vertically' at multiple levels in RDLC reports?

Tags: grouping, rdlc

I'm trying to write a report using RDLC with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition.

All my data is 'flattened' to a single row per item like this:

| Date | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 1 | First | This, that and the other |
| Jan 1 | First | More of the same |
| Jan 2 | First | Something about the second of Jan |
| Jan 2 | Second | And now a different type |
| Jan 2 | Second | And something else that belongs to this second type |

And I would like to group down the page, rather in across in columns, on Date, and then on Type:

**Jan 1**
*First*
This, that and the other
More of the same

**Jan 2**
*First*
Something about the second of Jan

*Second*
And now a different type
And something else that belongs to this second type

I can get an indented layout using row groups, but column groups, which SEEM to work down the page, do not produce an equivalent result as far as I can see.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

A recommendation for a good, useful guide to RDLC reports would also be appreciated!

I've tried both tables and lists as report items, and just about every combination of row and column groups, adjacent groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try do this?

1. Create Table
   [image: Step 1]
2. Make the Detail Group on Row to **Description** i use subcategory
   [image: Step 2]
3. Create Parent Group of Description with group header, for **Type** i use category
   [image: Step 3]
4. Create Parent Group of Type with group header for **Date** i use source
   [[image: Step 44]
5. Move the value to the last column
   [image: Step 5]
6. Remove every volumn except the last column and the top row

[image: Step 6]

Comment: Hi Rohan, sorry, I didn't realise you had answered this.

This seems to work so far -- thank you very much. How did you find this answer: is there a guide anywhere, because I can't find anything that discusses to a useful level how to achieve layouts in RDLC beyond just the default tabular layout.

Comment: Your Welcome...
Sorry i didn't have a link for the answer anymore...
I have similiar problems when doing my school project before...
So i just give the answer based on my experience...